# Other than the work by Watts Humphrey, what are good resources for the Personal Software Process?

Tags: process, personal-software-process

I'm interested in beginning to follow the PSP, even if it isn't the full process at first. And I might not even like it because of its rigid structure, as I learned in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197/do-you-follow-the-personal-software-process-does-your-organization-team-follow-t). I think that it will make me a better engineer, or at least let me find out more about my strengths and weaknesses so I can develop better habits. However, other than the Watts Humprey books [A Discipline for Software Engineering](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/A-Discipline-for-Software-Engineering/Watts-S-Humphrey/e/9780201546101/) and [PSP](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/PSP/Watts-S-Humphrey/e/9780321305497/), I'm not familiar with other good resources (preferably free - websites, blogs. paid resources also accepted) on the PSP.

What good resources are out there for a beginner?

Answer (score 3):

Carnegie Mellon has a degree program in Software Engineering that uses the PSP. The [course notes](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/tsp/) page has many links to news, notes, and exercises that are free and very useful for self-study.

Comment: There course notes appear to be available for course instructors, but I did download their self-study guide/notes. That might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the the process gurus' books is good. Up to a point, but in the end what will really help you mature is years of developing software in a variety of environments and with many types of teams, projects and people.  (This includes doing one-person development through organizations with thousands of developers and HUGE projects)

From those experiences (Assuming you are able to view the world around you) you can probably come up with your own ideas of personal, team and other processes and maturity levels.

The fact that you are interested in it and looking for answers about it is probably more important that subscribing to or reading a certain subset of authors or process books.

Read widely, practice software development and DO things.  After all, this work is about producing something - don't lose sight of that. As seems to happen too often - some people fall down the "process" rabbit hole and are rarely productive after that - they pursue process as an end in itself.  I should know - I drank the cool-aid early on but thankfully got a change of venue.

Anything you can do to rub elbows with developers from DIFFERENT kinds of teams or organizations is good - exposure to new practices and discussion of tools and practices is necessary to grow and learn.  You won't grow as fast without exposure to new ideas.  That does not mean you should jump on all the new, hot things that come along.  Many times they should be rejected or left to mature, but in some cases, hop on and go for the ride.

Don't be afraid to try things and fail.

Process is often very dependent on the organization/team you are part of.

Process sure does have its place, but it is secondary - not primary - to producing quality products.  Use your head and common sense.

EDIT

If you really really want names:

Gerald Weinberg has some decent books that are related to your questions.  Tom Demarco and Ed Yourdon also are on the list.

Comment: I think you are right - nothing but experience and learning what works and what doesn't, for you and your teams, is more beneficial than just reading the books. The only reason I'm focusing on the PSP is because it's one of the few (only?) process models geared toward one person, although I could adopt principles of other process models into it, I suppose. Might as well start with something, though. And thanks for the author suggestions. I'll look into what they have published and hopefully, will soon be able to come up with a personal process that works for me and with the process of my team.

Comment: BTW, that was exactly 600 characters. :P

Comment: I took a project management class where we used PSP to track our estimation and productivity on 6 projects through the quarter.  I think one of the primary benefits is giving you visibility into your "personal process" and pointing out areas where you can improve. Through the quarter my estimates became better and within +/- 5% of actual. If you can provide estimates with realistic error bounds your manager will love you!

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, I purchased the PSP book when it first came out followed it exactly.  I started programming in 1991 and following PSP and was a humbling experience to say the least.  It really teaches you the value of data collection so that you can understand your own process and how you estimate how long it takes to write any size of software.  Of course, I learned that I was way off my estimates, but over time it helped me become a better estimator and programmer (i.e. a better Software Engineer). I know you are looking for something that is free, but really a used PSP book on Amazon are less than $40 and I would say absolutely worth it.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much 'free' process books there are, look for anything from the following authors:
Tim Lister, Tom DeMarco, Ed Yourdon - but start with Code Complete: http://www.cc2e.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Code Complete was my first software book, however it's not that deep on process models and methodologies.